# Small office network - overload problem

Tags: routing, switch, router, wireless, ethernet

Dear fellow network engineers,

One of my friends has asked me to help him with his small office network.
It's a small accounting firm that has about 5 PC (desktops and laptops). They also have a 4TB NAS drive hooked up to the ISP router that they were provided. Here is a rough outline of the current office network setup:

[image: Current Office Setup]

I don't have the exact specs of the modem, but it's a low-end Huawei modem.

Their current problem comes from the fact that all traffic is handled by the small modem and when two or more devices attempt to backup data to the NAS drive, the modem overloads and restarts itself thus interrupting all backups in progress.

I am currently wondering as to how to remedy the situation. I am thinking of the following options:

1. Purchase a new better WiFi router with built-in ethernet switch that can handle the LAN traffic appropriately, but I how should I go about choosing a specific device?
2. Purchase an ethernet switch that can handle the traffic. This solution seems cheaper, but WiFi traffic is still going to be congested during backups?

Is there any other way to tackle this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to NE, the stack for Qs about professional Net Eng. I apologize for this paste-in comment, but I have to use this a LOT. Have you read our [What Can I Ask Here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We worked REALLY hard on it, and your Q does not fit [What Our Community Decided](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225) would be On-topic. Disagree? Please ask a Q in our parallel [Meta Net Eng](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com) including a link back to this Q and explain exactly where you feel it fits in our On-Topic list.

Answer (score 3):

A decent switch should solve your problem.  If everything is on the same VLAN, the traffic from a PC doing a backup will not impede any other PC trying to send traffic through the router since the traffic destined for the NAS will not flow through the router unless they are on different VLANs.  I assume they share a single VLAN based on your description of the low-end router.

Adding an AP that connects to the switch will solve your Wi-Fi problem for all but the Wi-Fi devices.